# object is being stored in database without the save() method JPA

Tags: java, jpa, lombok

Hello I have an endpoint, which sets a read-only object to be displayed on the return of the api.

However when I "SET" a variable of that object, it is store in database without the save() method;

ex:
a.setName(....)

Also, i'm using LOMBOK project

here's my code...

```
@GetMapping(value = "/block/actives", produces = APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public List<BotBlockDto> getListActiveBlock(@PathVariable Long botId, @PathParam("language") String language) throws Exception {
    return this.getBlockActives(botId, language);
}

public List<BotBlockDto> getBlockActives(Long botId, String language) {
    List<BotBlock> actives = blockService.findAllActivesByBotId(botId);
    
    if(language != null && !actives.isEmpty() && actives.get(0).getBot().isMultiLanguage()) {
        actives = blockService.nlpKeywordBlocksLanguage(botId, actives, language);
    }
    
    return null;
}

public List<BotBlock> nlpKeywordBlocksLanguage(Long botId, List<BotBlock> blocks, String language) {
    
    Map<Long, Map<String, BotBlockLanguage>> map = blockLanguageService.mapByBlockIdAndLanguage(botId);
    
    blocks.forEach(a -> {
        Map<String, List<String>> nlpKeywordsLanguages = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
        a.getNlpKeywords().forEach(b -> {
            if (!nlpKeywordsLanguages.containsKey(b.getLanguage())) {
                nlpKeywordsLanguages.put(b.getLanguage(), new ArrayList<String>());
            }
            nlpKeywordsLanguages.get(b.getLanguage()).add(b.getPhrase());
            a.setNlpKeywordsLanguages(nlpKeywordsLanguages);
        });
        
        if(a.getBot().isMultiLanguage()) {
            a.setAccessibleByNlpSoft(false);
            a.setAccessibleByNlp(false);
        }
        
        if (map != null && map.containsKey(a.getId())) {
            BotBlockLanguage blockLang = map.get(a.getId()).get(language);
            if(blockLang != null) {
                a.setAccessibleByNlpSoft(blockLang.isAccessibleByNlpSoft()); // store in database
                a.setAccessibleByNlp(blockLang.isAccessibleByNlp()); // store in database
                a.setName(blockLang.getName()); // store in database
            }
        }

    });
    return blocks;
}
```

is there a way to make this object read only? thanks.

Comment: If you don't wish any changes on your entities to get written to the Database, you'll need to detach that entity from the current persistence context: https://javaee.github.io/javaee-spec/javadocs/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html#detach-java.lang.Object-

Comment: how can I use detach in my context?, I'm thinking to use DTO in that case....

Comment: Unfortunately I don't know the exact answer myself, because there are so many different ways to use JPA and I'm not quite familiar with your setup. (In my projects i have access to an injected EntityManager directly). But transferring the data from the entities to some DTO object and then working on those objects with the data seems to be a good idea and solution that I often use myself.

Comment: o ok, @OHGODSPIDERS thanks!